# Power BI How to Sum Based on If a Column Contains String from Other Column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an Entity column with one row per entity. This table has three columns: Entity ID, a Descriptor, and a Metric. The Descriptor is a concatenation of numerous codes and I would like to see the metrics broken down by code.

I originally just split the Descriptor column into numerous rows but that led to some data relationship issues so I'd like to do it without splitting the Descriptor column.

[image: Desired Result]

I tried doing the following DAX formula but it resulted in an error stating "the expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression"

```
Desired Output Metric = CALCULATE('Metric',CONTAINSSTRING('Entity Table'[Descriptor],'Code Table'[Code]))
```

Ultimately I'm not even sure I need this as a column, and it may be better as a measure...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around "the expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression" by using Filter within your CALCULATE.

Here it is as a created column.  I used an IF because 'E' code evaluates to a blank and you wanted a 0.

```
Desired Output Metric = IF(CALCULATE(SUM('Entity Table'[Metric]),FILTER('Entity Table',CONTAINSSTRING('Entity Table'[Descriptor],'Code Table'[Code])))>0,CALCULATE(SUM('Entity Table'[Metric]),FILTER('Entity Table',CONTAINSSTRING('Entity Table'[Descriptor],'Code Table'[Code]))),0)
```

Here it is as a measure.  Be careful to only use this at the Code detail level.  When making a measure you need to use aggregate functions to reference your columns, so I am just doing the MIN(Code) since for any single code the Min() will always evaluate to equal that Code.  If you try to use this at a higher summary level you may get some odd answers as it will only total for the MIN() code in the data set you are referencing.

```
Desired Output Metric = IF(CALCULATE(SUM('Entity Table'[Metric]),FILTER('Entity Table',CONTAINSSTRING('Entity Table'[Descriptor],MIN('Code Table'[Code]))))>0,CALCULATE(SUM('Entity Table'[Metric]),FILTER('Entity Table',CONTAINSSTRING('Entity Table'[Descriptor],MIN('Code Table'[Code])))),0)
```

Comment: Wow that's something that I feel like I should have known by now. Thanks for the great insight! Unfortunately I'm realizing I DO need it to be a measure instead of a column and I don't think it works for a measure. When a measure, I'm limited to fields only in the entity table and am unable to use the code column in the containstring function.

Comment: @SebastianHubard Are you creating this column/measure in the Entity Table?  I think it makes more sense to add it to the Code table.  I have added the code for a measure, it is basically the same except you need to make the 'Code Table'[Code] an aggregate function like MIN() or MAX().

Comment: wow incredible i can't believe how easily you solved that haha thank you very much!